# What are the sequels to Rudin's Functional Analysis?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Briefly speaking my purpose, I'm looking for the sequels to Rudin's *Functional Analysis*. How about the following books by Stein? Are there any other nice ones?

- *Harmonic Analysis: Real-Variable Methods,...*
- *Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces*
- *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*

Comment: If you've finished Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, I would think at this point you would have a reasonable idea on what area of functional analysis you want to specialize in. If you include this additional information, then I think you'll get more response from others. If you want to continue more generally in all areas of functional analysis, there are plenty of more comprehensive treatises you can easily find on university library shelves (or use their on-line catalogues, going through all call numbers in the QA 320 vicinity), such as Kosaku Yoshida's book or Robert E. Edwards's book.

Comment: Your profile information says you're at Grinnell, which is about 70 miles from Iowa City (70 mph interstate all the way, so about an hour's dive), so you might want to look [here](http://infohawk.uiowa.edu/F/4FCSHB852PSDRJ4CUCSTBDQIU5BGP8HY69U5SKS8JUDYE9PYDJ-40850?func=scan&scan_start=QA320&scan_code=LCI) to get an idea of what's available at Univ. of Iowa's library. Of course, for simply getting a huge author/title list of possible books to google info. about, you can additionally do similar searches at dozens of other university libraries.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I found Yoshida's book in my college's library, so I will definitely check it as well as the books on your list!

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgeable about functional analysis, and I only mentioned Yoshida's and Edwards's books because I remember seeing (since the mid 1970s) these massive treatises on library shelves. Regarding Edwards's book, I found out (just now) that it's [been reprinted](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486681432) (cheaply) by Dover Publications.

Comment: The book by Brezis does partially overlap with Rudin's, but will give you a more up to date idea of what's functional analysis nowaday. If you are interested in operator theory, the book by Schmudge is an excellent one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As almost a year passed since my post, I'm now interested in operator theory more. So, I will check the operator theory book you mentioned.